# Exposing an F# Map type to C#

Tags: f#

I converted an C# Enum and Dictionary like so:

```
type Hosts = HostOne | HostTwo

type SiteHosts() as this = 
    inherit Dictionary<Hosts, string>()
    do 
        this.Add(Hosts.HostOne, "somewebsite.com")
        this.Add(Hosts.HostTwo, "anotherwebsite.com")
```

(...actually an `IReadOnlyDictionary` is exposed in C#... baby steps...)

Since `Map` exposes an `IDictionary` I thought I could just convert the dictionary to a map:

```
type SiteHostMap() as this =
    inherit Map<Hosts, string>()
    ~~~
```

But map is a sealed class so I can not subclass|inherit it.

I need to maintain C# compatibly, is there another way to expose a generic Map with immutable values (IReadOnlyDictionary) or I just thinking of this incorrectly

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Most of F# code I've seen avoids using inheritance. You can keep the map in a local field of the class and expose it as `IReadOnlyDictionary` through a member:

```
type Hosts = HostOne | HostTwo

type SiteHosts() = 
    let hosts = 
      [ Hosts.HostOne, "somewebsite.com"
        Hosts.HostTwo, "anotherwebsite.com" ] |> Map.ofList
    member x.Hosts : IReadOnlyDictionary<_, _> = hosts :> _
```

Comment: Perfect, thanks Tomas... simple now that I "see" it ;-) (need to borrow your brainpan for a couple of days... 